# Undocumented UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle values?

Tags: ios, uikit

I was just playing around with a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in a demo app, and happened to try setting invalid values to its style attribute.

Surprisingly, I found that other values are accepted by it as apparently valid styles. For example, setting its style to a value of `7` results in this:
[image: spinny indicator]
It seems that it will accept values in the range 0-21. Most of the styles are just size variations of the white and gray styles, with the exception of 9 and 10, which seem to be used as placeholder values when a custom color is set on one of the default styles (this is what the internal property _actualActivityIndicatorViewStyle is set to in these cases).

Does anyone have an idea what these are for?

Comment: They might be used internally by Apple. In any case if they're not documented then you shouldn't use them since there's no guarantee that they will continue to work.

Comment: nice discovery! i'd agree with @DuncanC , until they are documented i don't think it is safe to use them